# How to append custom styles in jade-bootstrap

Tags: css

I defined some custom styles (e.g. .box4) in starter-template.css, but apparently they are not used.
Even when I change the file name in the link, there is no error message because of the file, which does not exist.

starter.jade

```
extends ../_bootstrap
append styles
    // Custom styles for this template
    link(href='../css/starter-template2.css', rel='stylesheet')
```

home.jade

```
extends jade-bootstrap/layouts/starter

block body
    include ./includes/head.jade
    .container
        .row
            .box4
```

Answer (score 0):

if a css file is missing the error message is apparently in the log,not in the browser as expected.